# Confusion about the Definition of Pointed Hausdorff Topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For a metric space $M$, let $\mathscr{C}(M)$ denote the set of all closed sets in $M$. I have seen the **Hausdorff metric** on $\mathscr{C}(M)$  defined as $$ d(A,B) := \inf \lbrace   r > 0 \ | \  \forall p \in A, \exists q \in B  \ : \ d(p,q) < r,   \text{ and }      \forall q \in B, \exists p \in A  \ : \ d(p,q) < r    \rbrace, $$ and have studied properties of this. (Basically, it is the minimal $r$ such that all points of $A$ are within $r$ of $B$, and vice versa.)

Then,  the **pointed Hausdorff topology** takes a basis of open sets to be $N(A,K,r)$, for given $A \in \mathscr{C}(M),$ $K \subset M$ compact and $r > 0$, where $$N(A,K,r) :=   \lbrace   B  \in \mathscr{C}(M) \ | \ d(B \cap K, A \cap K) < r  \rbrace .  $$ It is claimed that **if $M$ is compact, then the pointed Hausdorff topology equals the Hausdorff metric topology.**

We shall denote H and PH for the two topologies.

**Confusion:** Does $N(A,K,r)$ include the sets $B$ with $B \cap K = \emptyset$? If so, this will mean that if $M$ is noncompact, all the basic open sets $N(A,K,r)$ will be very large. It will imply that there is ``wiggle room'' in the PH open sets, so that they are H open, and so H is stronger than PH. If $M$ is compact, then any H ball $B(A,r)$ is simply $N(A,M,r)$, so that H open sets are also PH open, and we have proven the claim.

On the other hand, enforcing that $B$ intersect $K$ in order to be in $N(A,K,r)$ is a closed condition that feels unnatural, and in particular, if we take $K = \lbrace p \rbrace$ a point, then for any set $A \ni 
  p, $ $N(A,\lbrace p \rbrace , r)$ is just all the closed sets containing $p$. It doesn't feel right, and also makes the claim fail.

The only problem is that *technically,* for any $A \neq \emptyset,$ we have $d(A, \emptyset) = \infty,$ since there is no $r > 0$ such that for all $p \in A$, *there exists* $ q \in \emptyset$ with $d(p,q) < r.$ So, in the above definition of PH topology, if $B \cap K = \emptyset,$  then $B$ is *not* in any $N(A,K,r).$ Of course, the solution to this is just to add the caveat "or, $B$ does not intersect $K$" in the definition of $N(A,K,r)$.

**Question:** Is everything I've said quite sound? In the standard definition, does the PH neighbourhood $N(A,K,r)$ indeed allow sets which do not intersect $K$, as I think it does?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $B\cap K=\emptyset$ and $A\cap K\ne \emptyset$, then $d(B\cap K,A\cap K)=\infty$ is not $<r$.

On the other hand, if $A\cap K=\emptyset$, then $N(A,K,r)$ consists *precisely* of those $B$ with $B\cap K=\emptyset$.

The reason is that the empty set is infinitely far away from any other closed set.

Comment: So, if $A = \lbrace p \rbrace$, then for $K = A$ and any $r>0$, $U := N(A,K,r)$ is all of the closed sets that pass through $p$? This contradicts the statement that PH = H in a compact space, since $U$ as given is not open w.r.t. the Hausdorff metric...